# Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel is showing and use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection; is showing Undefined type

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am working on a laravel project. I am trying to export my database value in an Excel sheet. I am using the maatwebsite/excel package. But my code is giving errors. This is my code in the Export folder. The FromCollection is showing undefine type also my Excel is showing undefined type. Please Help

In Export Folder :

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\usersModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

    class UsersExport implements FromCollection
    {
        /**
         * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
         */
        public function collection()
        {
            return usersModel::all();
        }
    }
```

My controller :

```
public function export()
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport(), 'users.xlsx');
    }
```

Comment: instead of "return usersModel::all();" try "return usersModel::all()->get();"

Comment: Can you share your ``usersModel`` class and your log files?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could show the error you got and the steps to reproduce it. In this case, probably you should also include how you added `maatwebsite/excel` to your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function export()
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');
    }
```

Your export file looks okay. Maybe try removing the

`/** * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection */`